# import dalvik.system.VMRuntime cannot find

Tags: java, android, vmrun

I am trying to import VMRuntime but i does not seem got

There were only got 3 packages which were `dexclassloader`, `dexfile` and `pathclassloader`.

`import dalvik.system.VMRuntime` <-- does not exist.

How to enable it?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that class VMRuntime was removed in API 9:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/9/changes/pkg_dalvik.system.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `VMRuntime` class in the Android SDK, let alone in [the `dalvik.system` package](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/package-summary.html). Hence, Eclipse is telling you that it does not exist in the Android SDK because it does not exist in the Android SDK.

Comment: so how can I use VMRuntime?